# What is a good way to acquire a target when approaching from low level flight?

Tags: dcs-world

What is the best way to get visual target acquisition in an A-10 when approaching from low level flight (< 500 feet)? If I fly directly towards where I believe the target to be, I end up missing because I don't have enough time to get the plane ready for weapons delivery before I overfly the target.  And overflying the target has...ended poorly for me.

I'm looking for a specific flight path (turn to this relative heading, climb to this altitude above ground level, roll in on target at this distance, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Approaching at a 45 degree angle relative to where the target might be should give me the time I need to acquire the target but still be moving towards it.

Specific flight path:
- Gauge the current air defenses and set altitude accordingly.
- Set the nose of the A-10 to 45 degrees relative to the target area.